# Remove server header in self hosted WebApi response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, self-hosting

We are using a self hosted WebApi and we are required to remove the server header (Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0) of the responses sent.

Since it is self hosted, a HttpModule is not an option. Implementing a `DelegatingHandler`, access to headers as well as adding is possible. The [asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) nicely details how one can do that.

But the server header seems to be added much later in the pipeline since it is not set in the `HttpResponseMessage` we return from the `DelegatingHandler`. However, we are able to add values.

```
async protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    response.Headers.Server.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("TestProduct", "1.0"));
    response.Headers.Add("Server", "TestServerHeader");

    return response;
}
```

Both `Server.Add` and `.Add` work as expected. `response.Headers.Remove("Server");` however does not work, because the server header is not set, `response.Headers.Server` is empty.

Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Just an idea, I haven't tried this myself. Message handlers, like `DelegatingHandler`-derived classes are executed very early in the Web API pipeline. It's worth trying to add your code in an `ActionFilter`-derived class, as action filters are executed much later in the pipeline, just before the controller actions. By then, perhaps the header you want will exist.

Comment: Thank you for @djikay for pointing this out, i did not know about `ActionFilterAttribute`. Unfortunately it seems it is still too early since the server header is not set when the Attribute executes.

Comment: Ah, I know why. This header is added by the hosting layer, which is the first layer hit when a request comes in and the *last* layer hit when a response goes out. Those headers ("Server" is just one of them) can be tough to remove. Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155176/removing-headers-from-the-response) and [this article](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/howardvanrooijen/archive/2009/08/25/cloaking-your-asp-net-mvc-web-application-on-iis-7.aspx). The latter is rather dated and talks about IIS hosting (not self-hosting), but it may give you some ideas.

Comment: This [forums.asp.net Q&A](http://forums.asp.net/t/1803242.aspx?Is+it+possible+to+programmatically+remove+the+custom+ASP+NET+headers+) also gives a short programmatic way to do this. I must emphasise that I haven't tried any of this myself so I can't tell you it will definitely work, I'm just hoping this will give you ideas.

Comment: @djikay thank you for the effort, but unfortunately all discussions you linked are only applicable if webapi is hosted via IIS7.

Answer (score 4):

add

```
appBuilder.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Server", new[] { "" });
            return next.Invoke();
        });
```

to Startup Configuration method just before

```
config.EnsureInitialized();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no code solution to remove Server HTTP header on self host.
The only solution is to edit windows registry:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/dsnotes/wswcf-remove-server-header